# Django: How to add Image of User in UserPostList View

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add the profile image of each user(designer) in the below list view

For each designer, there is a profile image that has already been uploaded before I am just trying to get it and show it in the UserPost List View.

Currently, with the below code, the designer image is not showing.

Here is the views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "user_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(designer=user, admin_approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        has_items = Item.objects.filter(designer__username=self.kwargs['username']).exists()
        context['has_items'] = has_items
        return context
```

Here is the template

```
{% if has_items %}
<h1> Hello, this is {{ view.kwargs.username }} </h1>
--------------------------------------
<img class="profile_image" src={{ designer.profile.image.url }}> <----------- I want it to appear

{% else %}

<h1>Hello, this is {{ view.kwargs.username }} </h1>
--------------------------------------
<img class="profile_image" src={{ designer.profile.image.url }}> <----------- I want it to appear
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You will need a ***form*** or HTML that supports the image upload functionality. The `ListView` *intended to work with GET requests* and which is not supported for ***form actions***

Comment: Probably this will help you, [Django image upload using form](https://www.google.com/search?q=Django%20image%20upload%20using%20form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The issue seems to be that your template is missing a `for` loop to loop through `posts` so that you can access the respective designer. Also, I'm assuming that `view` is accessible from a `post` object as it's not explicitly defined anywhere else in your code example. Lastly, your `else` loop is doing the same as the `if` loop.

## Solution

Include a `for` loop in template so that you can access designers' profile image URLs.

```
{% if has_items %}
{% for post in posts %}

<h1> Hello, this is {{ post.view.kwargs.username }} </h1>
--------------------------------------
<img class="profile_image" src={{ post.designer.profile.image.url }}>

{% endfor %}
{% else %}

...

{% endif %}
```

---

## References

- ListView Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview
- ListView Code https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L194

Comment: Hi, thanks I already have a for loop for posts below the conditions but this view is like a page for a designer so I just want the profile Image to appear once at the top not with each post. For loop will make it appear with each new object.

Comment: @A_K I am having the same problems.

Comment: I just want the profile Image to appear once at the top not with each post?

Comment: How can I access post outside of the for loop?